# Do keys for Google Cloud Storage files (created via create_gs_key() in GAE) expire eventually?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

...e.g. is it safe to put a few into the datastore and use them some months later for access, even though other files were later added to the bucket they reside in?

...or are they meant to be more like session-keys, which should be recreated any time you need them from a path?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can persist these keys indefinitely.

We acquire the access token on demand when you use the key.

[Note: The initial implementation of create_gs_key() did expire, so there might be some documentation around which says you cannot persist the key - this is no longer accurate.]

Comment: The doc string of google.appengine.api.blobstore.blobstore.create_gs_key in the GAE dev appserver says it's a short lived access token, and should not be stored permanently.  Needs update?

Comment: yup - can you file an issue in the issue tracker?